# How can I create a variable number of column headers in a table?

Tags: matlab, variable-names, matlab-table

[image: Here is a pic of a possible table.]

What I essentially want is for the headers

```
"Var1", ..., "VarN"
```

to be called

```
"Student no.", "Name", "Assignment 1", ..., "Assignment N-2"
```

I've tried messing around with the `T.properties.Variablenames` field, but can't seem to make it work (I can name "Var1" and "Var2" correctly, but not knowing how many assignments there's going to be makes me unable to name the rest of them).

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can first get the number of variable names in the table, then generate a set of strings for the assignments using [`sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) and [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html):

```
nVars = numel(T.Properties.VariableNames);
varNames = strsplit(sprintf('Assignment_%d ', 1:(nVars-2)));
T.Properties.VariableNames = [{'Student_no' 'Name'} varNames(1:(end-1))];
```

Note that the strings can't have spaces or periods in them (i.e. they follow the same format as [normal variable naming](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/variable-names.html) does).